# I do not understand what it meant by empty dataset in machine learning python

Tags: python, machine-learning, keras, dataset

```
import numpy as np
np.random.seed(10)
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from keras.models import load_model
import glob,cv2

def show_images_labels_predictions(images,labels,
                                  predictions,start_id,num=10):
    plt.gcf().set_size_inches(12, 14)
    if num>25: num=25 
    for i in range(0, num):
        ax=plt.subplot(5,5, 1+i)
       
        ax.imshow(images[start_id])
        
        
        if( len(predictions) > 0 ) :
            title = 'ai = ' + str(predictions[start_id])
           
            title += (' (o)' if predictions[start_id]==labels[start_id] else ' (x)') 
            title += '\nlabel = ' + str(labels[start_id])
      
        else :
            title = 'label = ' + str(labels[start_id])
            
         
        ax.set_title(title,fontsize=12) 
        ax.set_xticks([]);ax.set_yticks([])        
        start_id+=1 
    plt.show()
    
   
files = glob.glob("imagedata\*.jpg" )
test_feature=[]
test_label=[]
dict_labels = {"Cat":0, "Dog":1}
size = (80,80) 
for file in files:
    img=cv2.imread(file) 
    img = cv2.resize(img, dsize=size)       
    test_feature.append(img)
    label=file[10:13] 
    test_label.append(dict_labels[label])
   
test_feature=np.array(test_feature) 
test_label=np.array(test_label)     


test_feature_vector =test_feature.reshape(len(test_feature), 40,40,3).astype('float32')


test_feature_normalize = test_feature_vector/255

  

model = load_model('Pet_cnn_model.h5')
        

prediction = model.predict(test_feature_normalize)
prediction = np.argmax(prediction,axis=1)
    
   
show_images_labels_predictions(test_feature,test_label,prediction,0,len(test_feature))
```

Error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
~\AppData\Local\Temp/ipykernel_14064/1284467577.py in <module>
     58 
     59     #預測
---> 60 prediction = model.predict(test_feature_normalize)
     61 prediction = np.argmax(prediction,axis=1)
     62 

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\training.py in predict(self, x, batch_size, verbose, steps, callbacks, max_queue_size, workers, use_multiprocessing)
   1764             callbacks.on_predict_batch_end(end_step, {'outputs': batch_outputs})
   1765       if batch_outputs is None:
-> 1766         raise ValueError('Expect x to be a non-empty array or dataset.')
   1767       callbacks.on_predict_end()
   1768     all_outputs = tf.__internal__.nest.map_structure_up_to(batch_outputs, concat, outputs)

ValueError: Expect x to be a non-empty array or dataset.
```

For this program, can anyone explain what is the problem occurred in the line `prediction = model.predict(test_feature_normalize)`? As I am a beginner to learn machine learning in Python and I do not understand what it meant by `Expect x to be a non-empty array or dataset.` in the error message so any helps will be appreciated. However, for other images prediction programs, I could run the results and show which images have prediction errors so anyone could help me to figure out the problem?

Comment: Have you tried printing the shape of your `test_feature_normalize`?

Comment: Yes I did but do not know why it shows an empty list

Comment: I expect it should be something like this ```[0.3254902  0.35686275 0.3529412 ]
   [0.37254903 0.39215687 0.3882353 ]
   [0.42352942 0.42745098 0.42745098]``` that was from other programs I could run but do not know why this program has a problem

Comment: Step through your code in the debugger and find out where the variable becomes an empty array.

Comment: I can fix now because I found my image folder directory is not correct